# How to call object from test setup method to another method?

Tags: apex, developer

I am trying to write a test class, Where I created test setup method which creates and insert the object. I am trying to call the inserted object ID to another method. An error shows like **Variable does not exist: setup.WO**
My Code:

```
@isTest
public class WorkOrderControllerTest {
    @testSetup static void setup() {
        Work_Order__c WO = New Work_Order__c();
        WO.Job_Number__c = 'Test Job';
        WO.Trading__c = 'Painting';
        WO.Region__c = 'SFO';
        Insert WO;
    }
    static testMethod void test_getPaints(){
       WorkOrderController.getPaints(setup.WO.Id); //Variable does not exist: setup.WO
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help where did I go wrong ?

Comment: Please take a look https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_testsetup_using.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query the Work_Order__c object with that Job_Number__c field . You cannot get directly the data from one method to other methood.

```
 @isTest
public class WorkOrderControllerTest {
    @testSetup static void setup() {
        Work_Order__c WO = New Work_Order__c();
        WO.Job_Number__c = 'Test Job';
        WO.Trading__c = 'Painting';
        WO.Region__c = 'SFO';
        Insert WO;
    }
    static testMethod void test_getPaints(){

    Work_Order__c wro = [SELECT Id FROM Work_Order__c WHERE Job_Number__c ='Test Job' LIMIT 1];
       WorkOrderController.getPaints(wro.id); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In normal code, you'd be able to use class variables (static or instance) to hold and access data. If it's static variables, then you could simply access them using `ClassName.staticVariableName`. If it's instance variables, then you'd need to pass an instance into the method the you want to use it in. Pretty standard stuff.

Test classes are different though. Salesforce designed things in a way that means that:

- We can't pass variables in (to test methods)
- All static variables are cleared after your `@testSetup` method runs, but before each `@isTest` method is run (the `testMethod` keyword is deprecated, and should not be used)

In the end, to get at the information you created in your `@testSetup` method, you need to query for it. According to Salesforce, this still saves time over creating test data in every test method.